# How ASP.NET 4.6 injects dependencies?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have just started an ASP.NET 4.6 (MVC 5.2.3) using Visual Studio 2015 using the template, One thing that I saw was this code:

```
[Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public AccountController()
        {
        }

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }
}
```

As you can see along with default constructor we have second constructor that injects two dependencies, I would like to know, How does ASP.NET 4.6 do that? I didn't see any IoC container configuration

Comment: They are just parameters specific to that page.  They are not part of MVC or Asp.Net per se.     I have a controller for a page that orders Pears.  PearController()   and PearController(ShoppingCart curShopCart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. **It doesn't.**

By default, that constructor isn't being used. Instead, it instantiates those objects when they are accessed.

```
public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
{
    get
    {
        return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    }
    private set 
    { 
        _signInManager = value; 
    }
}

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

In this case, the getter is using the [Null coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) `??` to create the object if it doesn't exist.

The MVC team has put that constructor there for you to use if you want.

Comment: Since this came up as a first answer on google, can you elaborate on how we (noobs) are supposed to go about getting DI working for 4.6?

Comment: Start by looking at the [documentation page on Dependency Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dependency-injection/topics).